# Problema em requisição com jQuery ($.ajax) e Angular ($http)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Estou tentado obter da forma mais rápida e direta alguns dados de uma API. Utilizando o Postman eu consigo isso facilmente apenas dando um GET na url (http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos), assim obtenho:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "grupos": [
    {
      "Titulo": "A inteligência emocional do seu corpo",
      "ID": 1
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional em família",
      "ID": 2
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional em sociedade",
      "ID": 3
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional no trabalho",
      "ID": 4
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional nas férias",
      "ID": 5
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional no dia a dia",
      "ID": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Porém quando eu tento fazer um GET utilizando jQuery ou Angular, não consigo. Abaixo seguem as duas chamadas e os erros que eu obtenho.

1. Utilizando jQuery

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSONP',
     url: 'http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/',
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(e) {
       console.log(e);
     }
   }).done(function( data ) {
     console.log("done ", data);
   })
   .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log('erro');
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
       console.log(textStatus);
       console.log(errorThrown);
   });
   ```

> - Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}
> - erro
> - undefined
> - parsererror
> - Error: jQuery111108493785087484866_1448911631891 was not called(…)

2. Utilizando Angular

   ```
   $http.jsonp('http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/ListarGrupos')
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $log.error(data);
     $log.error(status);
     $log.error(headers);
     $log.error(config);
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $log.log(data);
     $log.log(status);
     $log.log(headers);
     $log.log(config);
   });
   ```

> - undefined
> - (d){b||(b=ad(a));return d?(d=b[F(d)],void 0===d&&(d=null),d):b}
> - Object {method: "JSONP", transformRequest: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNJG.png), transformResponse: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNJG.png), url:
>     "http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos", headers: Object}

Obs.: Eu consigo ver o retorno, porém ele é apresentado como erro, assim não consigo manipular os dados. Veja!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Importante! Não tenho acesso a API, por isso serão bem vindas soluções que se prendam a alguns dos métodos propostos (jQuery ou Angular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando usar JSONP para acessar a API porém a mesma não parece suportar o mesmo.

Se esta API é sua e você pode modificá-la existem duas coisas que podem ser feitas, uma delas é dar suporte a JSONP, porém teria que ter cuidado com quem já usa ela e espera que o resultado seja simplesmente JSON, e a outra seria adicionar os cabeçalhos do CORS para permitir o acesso a esta API de outros domínios, lembrando que isso deve ser feito no lado da API e não do lado de quem a consome.

Se estas alternativas não forem possíveis existe sempre a possibilidade de você fazer as requisições no servidor. Basicamente você cria uma API nova em seu site que funcione como uma espécie de proxy para a API externa, assim usaria o jQuery ou Angular para fazer a requisição para o servidor que hospeda o seu site, onde não existem restrições e este faria a requisição para a API externa.

Comment: O jeito será mexer na API. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 0):

Vai ter que modificar o retorno do serviço, já que é um `JSONP`.

**Retorno atual:**

```
{"error":0,"grupos":[{"Titulo":"A inteligência emocio...}
```

**Retorno correto:**

```
callback({"error":0,"grupos":[{"Titulo":"A inteligência emocio...})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19166256/1803238

Comment: JBJ era justamente isso que eu não gostaria de fazer. Pois mexer na API implica mexer em um sistema desktop legado.

Comment: Pode usar CORS no serviço?